# How to find the location of a specific word in an audio file?

Tags: android, audio, media, audio-recording, flac

I am developing an android application for media related work. In this application I have a recorded sound file, which is in `flac` format (you can forget the format, I can convert it). The sound file will play the below.....

```
I am here my friend <silence> just do it soon
```

Now, if my concentration is only for the word `friend`. Is there any way for me to find out where exactly this word `friend` is located in the sound file? For an example, if the sound file is 10 seconds long, then it should tell me the word `friend` is between `0.2 - 0.4` seconds or something like that.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I did a similar app with this Watson api:
https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/speech-to-text/

Convert the sound to text and then with the json search the response.

```
    {
  "result_index": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "final": true,
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "hello world",
          "confidence": 0.9,
          "timestamps": [["hello",0.0,1.2],["world",1.2,2.5]],
          "word_confidence": [["hello",0.95],["world",0.866]]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: The text output is not the problem, problem is finding exactly in which place (between which second to which second) the particular word appeared in the sound file.

Comment: The response include the second, i edited the answer

Comment: oh, thats interesting, Any android examples?

Comment: We have a php script that convert the audio and we get the response.
You can do it with nodejs too.